# Tell GIT to ignore certain files

Tags: git, gitignore

I've tried including the `.gitignore` file in my directories of my project. In this file is the filename `config.php`. What I'm trying to do is get it so that each system (Development 1, Dev 2 and Test Server) all have their own `config.php` files.

But I've placed this file `.gitignore` in the directory where that file resides but that file is still synced when `pushing` and still merged. It also pulls it down to the test server when we sync that up. So each time we have to edit that file.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Just now saw the dupe post. It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things can be happening here:

1. I've only ever seen `.gitignore` files in the root of the repository. This might not be required, just the only way I've ever seen it.
2. If the file in question is already under version control, you must delete it from version control, commit, push, and then put the file back. The `.gitignore`, if configured correctly, should prevent the file from being committed.

Comment: In my opinion both points are correct to have a proper configuration. First move the .gitignore in the root folder (best location in my opinion) and then remove the file from the index in order to have the desired behaviour.

Comment: +1 for comment using the word "index." I couldn't remember how they termed it!

Comment: So I log into bitbucket and delete the file from my master and all other branches to make this file work?

Comment: I'm no Git expert, but I would think that your local repository is only tied to one branch. You should be able to remove the file from your local repository's index, commit, push, and it should be good. [Related SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223308/how-to-remove-a-file-from-the-index-in-git)