# How do I delete file in Git?

Tags: git

I want to delete a file in git. But also I want it to be seen in the history. Can I just right click, delete and then commit it? Or, is there a command for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a file from the index in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223308/how-to-remove-a-file-from-the-index-in-git)

Comment: @pjmorse its what I don't ask. It asks the opposite one. So the question you are pointing is not related with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use git rm, then commit

```
git rm abc.txt
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm