# .gitignore is been tracked after use git add -A

Tags: git

I try to use `git add -A` to keep git repo working directory same as staging area, but unfortunately, the `.gitignore` file also add into the staging area. So how to recovery to make it untracked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a file from the index in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223308/how-to-remove-a-file-from-the-index-in-git)

Comment: You *want* to track the ignore file, otherwise anywhere else you clone the repo to would not ignore the files it specifies.

Comment: Can you show us your `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, take it out of the staging area (to do so, follow the advice `git status` prints).  Then simply add `.gitignore` as a line in the `.gitignore` file, so that you tell your Git not to add `.gitignore` to tracked files when you run `git add`.

It's unusual to want to *avoid* tracking the `.gitignore` file though.  If it is important to tell Git not to add file `foo.out`, `database.db`, and so on, to the staging area, isn't it important to *save* the information that Git should not add these files to the staging area?