# In Git, how do I diff to the first commit of my branch?

Tags: git, git-diff

I've made several commits to a local branch, but I'm not sure what the best way to diff what I currently have to my branch's starting state.  I know I can do something like `git diff HEAD HEAD~6` if there's been 6 commits to my branch, but I was hoping for something that was independent of the number of commits.

Edit:
I failed to mention this: I was hoping I wouldn't have to dig through the log to get the hash of the commit I branched from.  If I had 80 commits for example, this wouldn't be a fun task.

Also, presume that the original branch I branched from has already had several changes.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You'll want to use the triple dot syntax described in `git help diff`:

```
git diff otherbranch...
```

This is the same as:

```
git diff otherbranch...HEAD
```

which is the same as:

```
git diff $(git merge-base otherbranch HEAD) HEAD
```

The `merge-base` command prints the "best" (most recent) common ancestor, so the above command shows the difference from the most recent commit that `HEAD` has in common with `otherbranch` to `HEAD`.

Note you can use `@{u}` in place of `otherbranch` to see the changes you made since you diverged from the upstream branch.  See `git help revisions` for details about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [find the commit you branched from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git). Once you have that, you can simply do a `git diff <branch-point>..HEAD` (as yasouser pointed out).

Answer (score -1):

`git diff <SHA-1 of the commit from which you branched>..HEAD`

You can get the SHA-1 of your branch point by doing a `git log`.

Comment: Yeah, this works.  I guess I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve me digging though the log to find the SHA-1 hash.  (Like, if I had 80 local commits for example).