# Git: Generate patch of all commits made on "feature" branch without referring to commit IDs

Tags: git, branch, patch, format-patch

We maintain two versions of our application in two branches: `free` and `master` (`master` being the premium version of our application). These branches are fairly similar but the `master` branch has a few extra application features that the `free` version doesn't, so we need to maintain the two branches ongoing.

Regularly we need to fix bugs or add features to the `free` branch, which we need to have applied to the `master` branch when they're done. When I have such work to do, I'll start a new branch based on `free` called, for example, `newfeature`. When I'm done the feature, `newfeature` has X new commits.

Before I merge `newfeature` back into `free` I'd like to know what command I can use to generate a patch from all the commits contained in `newfeature` that now need to be applied to `master`. Currently, I'm just doing this:

```
git format-patch aa99f9..e94904
```

As far as I know how to do, I have to actually look up the specific commit IDs of when I branched `newfeature`, and the last commit in `newfeature`, which is a drag. I'm not interesting in commit IDs and I don't want to have to type them in.

I want there to be a single command that I can consistently use in which *git will figure out which commits I'm talking about*. It's the same pattern every time: given branch `newfeature`, I want to generate a patch of the commits from the **common ancestor of `newfeature` and `free`** to the **latest commit on `newfeature`**.

Is there some changeset expression out there that will obviate the need to manually look up commit IDs?

P.S.: AFAIK, I cannot use `git rebase` to do this task because that will merge the entire `free` branch onto `master`. I just want to merge the commits that are unique to the `newfeature` branch onto `master`.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `git merge-base`.  See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git for complicated version of merge base finding and usage, but a simple `A...B` will probably work for many of your cases.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically what you're asking for is:

```
git format-patch `git merge-base newfeature free`..newfeature
```

You could probably save some time by doing this:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick `git merge-base newfeature free`..newfeature
```

Depending on your workflow, you might just have to create the patch before you merge in your feature.  i.e.:

```
git checkout newfeature
git rebase free
git format-patch free
```

It does sound a but like your workflow could be improved by simply basing premium off of free and merging the free features into the premium branch.