# Git post-checkout hook on new branches only

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to create a git hook that is run after a checkout only if a new branch was checked out (i.e. the `-b` flag was used). I'm using a `post-checkout` hook and have tried various techniques to get this working like checking oldrev.

Is `post-checkout` the hook I want? If so what logic should I use in the script so the hook only takes effect when a new branch is checked out?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, once created, a "new" branch is indistinguishable from an "old" branch.

Comment: I don't think git provides a way to do what you want.  You might be able to get occasional success by seeing how many reflog entries there are though.

Comment: Thanks, previous to asking my question I read the question mentioned above as a possible duplicate. The answers to it address how to use the post-checkout hook, but don't answer the questions of detecting a new branch.

Comment: @westonkd I don't think that's possible in a more reliable manner than [that suggested by Andrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047579/git-post-checkout-hook-on-new-branches-only#comment40805108_26047579).

Comment: Its over a year later, have things changed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not finding the hook (a `post-checkout` hook can be used).
It is to detect that a new local branch has just been created.

But "new" compared to which branch? [Detecting a "branch point"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12971503/6309) is tricky, considering you don't know which starting branch to consider.

You can also [check the reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182000/6309) to verify that the branch has been checked out once.

Or, you could also maintain a cache of the local branches: the output of `ls .git\refs\heads`, saved somewhere as a file being said "cache".
Each time the `post-checkout` hook is fired up, it would do the `ls .git\refs\heads`
and compare it with its cache. If a new entry is seen (and there is no similar branch in `.git\refs\remotes\origin`), chances are: this is a new local branch created for the very first time.
Then the hook would update the cache file.