# List all modified files in git merge commit - even the fast forwarded

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I'm thinking if there is a way that when I merge a branch into another branch that ALL changed files are listed in my commit message and not just the ones which were modified in both branches.
This would give me a better overview of what was changed in the branch just by seeing the merge commit.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think for fast forward commits you'll be able to do that.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I don't know how to do that in the commit message.  But after the merge, this will give the names of all the files affected by the merge commit:

```
git log -m --name-only
```

For only a list of filenames of the commit:

```
git log -m -1 --name-only --pretty="format:" <Merge SHA>
```

There is some white space due to the merge having two parents but that can be easily removed.

Comment: this also justs lists all the commits (of course incl. the file names) but I just want to have a list of files

Comment: add a -1 to the command.  Updated my answer further to only show file names.

Comment: Thanks for this! I can't find `-m` or `-1` documented anywhere today (though they still work). Have these options ben renamed?

Comment: The -1 is in the documentation as -<number>, you can limit the log to any number of commits.  I can seem to find the documentation for `-m` either though but it is shown as one of the examples.

Comment: **-m** is for the following and is a *diff formatting* option: This flag makes the merge commits show the full diff like regular commits; for each merge parent, a separate log entry and diff is generated. An exception is that only diff against the first parent is shown when --first-parent option is given; in that case, the output represents the changes the merge brought into the then-current branch.

Comment: -m is in the Diff Formatting section of `git help log`. It unfortunately does not have a long option name.

Comment: @elijah : or `git log help`.

Comment: `-m -1` returns for some reason all commits merged in current branch, so I use `git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1` from @R0MANARMY' s answer

Comment: I came here looking for something that lists the changed files just merged into the main branch. My solution was `git log -m --name-status -1 --first-parent --pretty="format:"`

Comment: Shows irrelevant files as well (from the prev. merge). I found that `tig` CLI tool shows the files more correctly

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the [`diff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) command to see the difference between any two commits.  If the branches haven't been merged yet, you can specify the branch names and compare them, otherwise you might need to find where they diverged *([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git))* an the last commit before they were merged back together.

```
git diff --name-status <commit> <commit>
```

> `-name-status` Show only names and status of changed files.

Answer (score 5):

suppose you have SHA of your merge commit, then
`git diff --name-only <SHA>^1 <SHA>`