# Git diff working incorrect - to many changes

Tags: git, git-diff

```
           f1---f2                 - short term branch "feature1"
          /       \
      h--h--h---h--h1--h2-         - long term branch "hofix"
     /       \   \      \
    /         \   \      \
   m----m------m---m------m--      - long term branch "master"
                   |      |
                 1e1e1e 2f2f2f
```

I merge branches with 2 commits difference (15 file changed totaly).
And ran:

```
$ git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 1e1e1e..2f2f2f
```

I receive more than 42 000 file changed from my project. Why?

Expected: i will show diff with f1,f2,h1,h2 commits

P.S. May be because "Merge branch 'origin/0411-hotfix'" commit?

Comment: What does `git merge-base 1e1e1e 2f2f2f` returns? Which '`h`'?

Comment: this rarely happens, in 1 from 5 case.
I can not catch it.

Answer (score 5):

`1e1e1e..2f2f2f` means:

- all commits that are reachable from `2f2f2f`
- excluding those that are reachable from `1e1e1e`

(See "[SPECIFYING RANGE](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_ranges)" from [`gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html))

If those SHA1s reference the two commits merged, you have:

```
    1e1e1e
      |
x--x--x
       \
        Z
       /
y--y--y
      |
    2f2f2f
```

That would give you all the files from all '`y`' commits, which can potentially go as far as the very first commit, and that means you get all the files.

However, since [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) *doesn't* take a range of commits (as opposed to [`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)), you can try, as in "[How to “`git show`” a merge commit with combined diff output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335580/6309)":

```
git diff --name-only 1e1e1e..2f2f2f
```

Or simply use the merge SHA1 '`Z`', as in "[List all modified files in git merge commit - even the fast forwarded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14717120/6309)":

```
git log -m -1 --name-only --pretty="format:" <Merge SHA>
```