# Re-merge from earlier branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Lets say I have three branches, `W`, `M` and `F`. Branch `W` is the one I am working on, branch `M` is "master", and branch `F` is an earlier bug-fixing branch. `W` is based on `M`, `F` have been merged into `M` some time ago. `W` have been synced (merged) from `M` from time to time.

Something like

```
   ,--.  branch F
  /    \
-+------+--+------+------+------+------   branch M
            \      \      \      \
             `------+------+------+----   branch W
```

The problem is that after the merge of `F` into `M`, those changes were missed in a merge from `M` to `W`. So now I want to merge from `F` into `W`, but git says that branch `W` already is up-to-date, which technically it is but it's still missing the parts from `F`.

How can I re-merge from `F` into `W`?

I want something like

```
       ,--+-----------------------------------.       branch F
      /    \                                   \
     /      \       ,------+------+------+------+---  branch W
    /        \     /      /      /      /
---+----------+----+-----+------+------+------------  branch M
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is one case where `git cherry-pick` would be easier than attempting a merge.

See "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1994463/6309)".

If "`F`" still references the commit before the merge into `M`, you can use the range `M..F`
(ie. all commits accessible from `F`, but not from `M`).

```
git checkout W
git cherry-pick M..F
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, git reported "empty commit set passed" for that.

Comment: I also tried just `git cherry-pick F` and it merges *some* of the things from `F` but not all.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg strange `fatal: empty commit set passed` means the range of commit you passed is empty (http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/cherry-pick-revert-error-messages-td7013134i40.html)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg try first to list the commits you want, with a `git log`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20095458/6309 (without the `--name-only`). then try the cherry-pick with that range of commits.