# List of files changed or updated during the last pull request in git version control

Tags: git, pull-request

How to find the list of files that are changed or added during the last pull request.

Is there any specific command to identify the list of files changed in last pull request when conflit is not occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717120/list-all-modified-files-in-git-merge-commit-even-the-fast-forwarded), you can use

`git log -m -1 --name-only --pretty="format:" <Merge SHA>`

Another way of doing that would be to use

`git log`

You'll get a list of all the commits, where you can grab the latest commit "hash" (I don't know what's the exact terminology for that) and use

`git show`

You'll see which files are changed and what  was changed in them.

Comment: git log command shows only the commits of particular author order by last updated date desc, and git show only shows local changes that are done at local level.

Comment: when you use git show with the commit hash you'll see a list of all the files changed. So when you rebase or merge with the lastest code, you can `git log` get the hash of the latest commit, then `git show <commit-hash>` and see which files are altered.

Comment: @JaypalSodha I edited my answer please take a look.

Comment: Glad I could help :)