# Git Show of a merge commit listing more files than the merged files

Tags: gitlab, git-merge, git-show

I have 3 Feature branches and 1 Release branch. I merged code from Feature1 to Release having 2 commits. Then i am merging code from feature2 to Release having 1 commit. When i execute the git show command with 2nd merge commit its listing all the files instead of showing only feature2 merged files.

git show -m -1 6929195e --name-only --stat --pretty=format:

I want my merge commit id to list only merged files from particular branch instead of showing all the files. Please reply if you dont understand my questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list only changed files you could use `git diff <SHA>^1 <SHA>`

If your case:

```sh
git diff --name-only 6929195e^1 6929195e
```

Inspired by [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58503819/10950272)

Answer (score 1):

If your last commit is a *merge commit* generated after merging `feature2` into `master`, then you can use the following command to get the list of merged files from the `feature2`:

```
git show --first-parent <merge-commit-SHA> --name-only --pretty=format:
```