# How to get commit history for just one branch?

Tags: git, git-log

Let's say I created a new branch `my_experiment` from  `master` and made several commits to `my_experiment`. If I do a `git log` when on `my_experiment`, I see the commits made to this branch, but also the commits made to `master` before the `my_experiments` branch was created.

I would find it very useful to see the history of all commits to the `my_experiments` branch until it hits the creation of that branch - effectively a true history of just that branch. Otherwise it's not clear to me when looking through the log whether the commits were on the `my_experiments` branch or not.

Is there a way to do this with Git?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You can use a [range](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) to do that.

```
git log master..
```

If you've checked out your `my_experiment` branch. This will compare where `master` is at to `HEAD` (the tip of `my_experiment`).

Comment: Ok spoke too soon. That did it for my simple example. But now I'm looking at somebody else's real repo and it occurs to me that in order to use this command properly, I'd need to know what branch my current branch was created from. Maybe I should be able to tell this from gitk but it's not obvious to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Marplesoft It can be complicated to figure that out. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1527234/31671).

Comment: Could you explain briefly how does it work? What does `git log master..` tell to Git?

Comment: @tonix Follow the link in the answer for more information on how a *range* works (the `master..`) part.

Comment: If your current branch was created from develop, use `git log develop..` ; if it was created from main, use `git log main..`, and so on.

Answer (score 20):

Note: if you limit that log to the last n commit (last 3 commits for instance, git log -3), make sure to put a space between 'n' and your branch:

```
git log -3 master..
```

Before Git 2.1 (August 2014), this mistake: `git log -3master..` would actually show you the last 3 commits of the current branch (here `my_experiment`), ignoring the `master` limit (meaning if `my_experiment` contains only one commit, 3 would still be listed, 2 of them from `master`)

See [commit e3fa568](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3fa568cb397a78a56716137c826f21f5e0b0a77) by  [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster):

### revision: parse "`git log -<count>`" more carefully

> This mistyped command line simply ignores "`master`" and ends up showing two commits from the current `HEAD`:

```
$ git log -2master
```

> because we feed "`2master`" to `atoi()` without making sure that the whole string is parsed as an integer.
>
> Use the `strtol_i()` helper function instead.

Comment: last command gives `fatal: '2master': not a non-negative integer`, so I think there is no need to mention it anymore..

Comment: @Bersan I mention it because that was the case for Git older than 2.1.

Answer (score 10):

The `git merge-base` command can be used to find a common ancestor.  So if my_experiment has not been merged into master yet and my_experiment was created from master you could:

```
git log --oneline `git merge-base my_experiment master`..my_experiment
```

Comment: If you want to include the parent of your first commit, add **^** and **--first-parent** :  `git log --oneline \`git merge-base my_experiment master\`^..my_experiment --first-parent`

Comment: Quick note: You don't really need ` --oneline` unless there are too many commits and you want to condense the total number of lines in the output.

Answer (score 6):

You can use only `git log --oneline`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

I think an option for your purposes is `git log --oneline --decorate`. This lets you know the checked commit, and the top commits for each branch that you have in your story line. By doing this, you have a nice view on the structure of your repo and the commits associated to a specific branch. I think reading [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late for this one... But here is a (not so simple) oneliner to get what you were looking for:

```
git show-branch --all 2>/dev/null | grep -E "\[$(git branch | grep -E '^\*' | awk '{ printf $2 }')" | tail -n+2 | sed -E "s/^[^\[]*?\[/[/"
```

- We are listing commits with branch name and relative positions to actual branch states with `git show-branch` (sending the warnings to `/dev/null`).
- Then we only keep those with our branch name inside the bracket with `grep -E "\[$BRANCH_NAME"`.
- Where actual `$BRANCH_NAME` is obtained with `git branch | grep -E '^\*' | awk '{ printf $2 }'` (the branch with a star, echoed without that star).
- From our results, we remove the redundant line at the beginning with `tail -n+2`.
- And then, we finally clean up the output by removing everything preceding `[$BRANCH_NAME]` with `sed -E "s/^[^\[]*?\[/[/"`.

Comment: This doesn't work if the branch has been merge into master. It only reports history back to the merge point, not all the way back to the creation of the branch. I believe it's not possible to get back beyond the closest merge point, given the reflog can be gc'd.

Comment: well, you can always use this [amazing perl script](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts/blob/master/git-forest) from [Jan Engelhardt](https://github.com/jengelh). I use it very often with `--all --reverse` params...