# How to checkout git state before merge?

Tags: git

I merged a git branch into my master, but now I want to get the state of the code before the merge. I do not want to revert the merge. How do I do this? Running `git log` shows hundreds of commits, but doesn't list the branch, so I'm not sure how to find the commit hash. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974204/how-to-get-commit-history-for-just-one-branch) recommends running `git log master..` but this returns nothing for me.

Answer (score 3):

If the merge commit is `HEAD`, the commits that were merged are `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2` (and so on, if there are more than two parents). Check it out!

```
git checkout master^2  # probably the branch merged in
git checkout master^1  # probably master before the merge
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to find hash (HEAD):

```
git reflog
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git reflog` to see the history, you'll see something like this:

```
72387432 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{4}: pull: Fast-forward
3df12c55 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from dev to master
```

The merge happened at `72387432`, I know this because of the pull (in my case the merge came from a git pull, after merging the PR in bitbucket).  So what you want is to checkout right before that which is `3df12c55`:

```sh
git checkout 3df12c55
```

Now you can check the code, do tests, etc. When you want to get back to master you can just run `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not deleted your merged branch yet. Then you can use

> git log branchMerged..master

It will list down all the commits which are present in master and not present in branch which you merged.

Here branchMerged : Name of the branch which you have merged. And I assume you have merged in master.