# List all commits in a topic branch

Tags: git

I have a feature branch concisely named `feature` that has about 100 commits all related to a feature of sorts. These commits were all merged into the master branch over the time. I want to list all commits that were on the branch so I can re-add the feature to other project.

Basically I want to have commit IDs for the green dots on the graph below.

[image: relevant commits]

How can I do that in Git other then by going to gitk or similar tool and hand-collecting all the relevant commit IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite answer is given and accepted I would suggest more automatic way for doing this (but it will only work if you did not merge your `master` to `feature`):

Considering the following history:

```
--A---B---C---D---E---F---G (master)
       \     /       /
        H---J-------K       (feature)
```

Basically we want to perform `git log B..feature`.

```
git log --format='%H' feature..master | tail -1 | \
xargs -I '{}' git log '{}'^..feature
```

`git log --format='%H' feature..master | tail -1` will find the commit to the `master` that was done right after you created `feature` branch - this is `C`

And ancestor of `C` - `B` will also be the ancestor of the first commit `H` of `feature` branch.

Then `xargs -I '{}' git log '{}'^..feature` (that is turns to `git log B..feature`) just shows the commits that is reachable from `feature` but don't reachable from the `B`.

Comment: I have a somewhat messy beginning of the `feature` branch requiring to hand-pick starting commit, but otherwise your recipe works just fine. Here's one-liner: `git log $(git rev-list feature..master | tail -1)^..feature`

Comment: see [Finding a branch point with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1527234) for details on how to find a branch start point

Answer (score 6):

If you get the starting point of the specific branch, e.g., `SHA1`, try this:

```
git log --pretty=oneline SHA1^..feature
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version, possible with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022):

```
git log --exclude-first-parent-only feature ^master
```

That will list all commits from `feature` branch.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/708cbef33a2c905c920e94b70d0946f9f4ff3a4e/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> and friends learned an option `--exclude-first-parent-only` to propagate UNINTERESTING bit down only along the first-parent chain, just like `--first-parent` option shows commits that lack the UNINTERESTING bit only along the first-parent chain.

See [commit 9d505b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d505b7b49c00c5fa99a25506e63a2ef326a0062) (11 Jan 2022) by [Jerry Zhang (`jerry-skydio`)](https://github.com/jerry-skydio).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 708cbef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/708cbef33a2c905c920e94b70d0946f9f4ff3a4e), 17 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d505b7b49c00c5fa99a25506e63a2ef326a0062): add --exclude-first-parent-only flag
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> It is useful to know when a branch first diverged in history from some integration branch in order to be able to enumerate the user's local changes.
> However, these local changes can include arbitrary merges, so it is necessary to ignore this merge structure when finding the divergence point.
>
> In order to do this, teach the "`rev-list`" family to accept "`--exclude-first-parent-only`", which **restricts the traversal of excluded commits to only follow first parent links**.
>
> ```
> -A-----E-F-G--main
>   \   / /
>    B-C-D--topic
> ```
>
> In this example, the goal is to return the set **`{B, C, D`}** which represents a topic branch that has been merged into `main` branch.
> [`git rev-list topic ^main`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d505b7b49c00c5fa99a25506e63a2ef326a0062/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> will end up returning no commits since excluding `main` will end up traversing the commits on `topic` as well.
> [`git rev-list --exclude-first-parent-only topic ^main`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d505b7b49c00c5fa99a25506e63a2ef326a0062/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L139)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---exclude-first-parent-only))</sup>  however will return `{B, C, D}` as desired.
>
> Add docs for the new flag, and clarify the doc for `--first-parent` to indicate that it applies to traversing the set of included commits only.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d505b7b49c00c5fa99a25506e63a2ef326a0062/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L125-L132):

> When finding commits to include, follow only the first
> parent commit upon seeing a merge commit.
>
> This option
> can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of
> a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic
> branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream
> from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore
> the individual commits brought in to your history by such
> a merge.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d505b7b49c00c5fa99a25506e63a2ef326a0062/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L139-L145):

> ### `--exclude-first-parent-only`
>
> When finding commits to exclude (with a '{caret}'), follow only
> the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit.
>
> This can be used to find the set of changes in a topic branch
> from the point where it diverged from the remote branch, given
> that arbitrary merges can be valid topic branch changes.

Comment: See a practical example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193866/6309