# List commits in git branch

Tags: git, github

I want to list all commits added to *feature* branch that are not on *master*. Something like a list of commits on github pull request page.

I've periodically pulled from *master* but also have some local merges (both sides belong to feature branch) since there were many people working in that branch so I can't exclude all merges or limit to first parent.

There are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779631/list-all-commits-in-a-topic-branch) that suggest `git log master..feature` but when I've tried that it also listed commits from *master* that were merged into *feature*. Adding `--cherry` or changing to triple dot didn't help at all and the former breaks gitk.

Comment: According to git-rev-parse man page: "This set operation appears so often that there is a shorthand for it. When you have two commits r1 and r2 (named according to the syntax explained
       in SPECIFYING REVISIONS above), you can ask for commits that are reachable from r2 excluding those that are reachable from r1 by ^r1 r2 and it can
       be written as r1..r2."

Git log master..feature should show all commits reachable from feature and NOT reachable from master, so, there is now way you see any commit from master when doing git log master..feature.

Comment: You are correct and thanks for pointing to authoritative documentation. Turns out I was comparing wrong things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I realize my mistake. I was doing `master..feature` but my local `master` branch was far behind `origin/master` from which I was doing merges. Using `git log origin/master..feature` is a far better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`git cherry`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry). It will find those commits that hasen't yet been merged to upstream (in your case that's master).

Comment: If git log --cherry isn't working properly then git cherry isn't going to either.