# Find branching point from post-receive hook

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, git-post-receive

**tl;dr: find branching point from post-receive hook only using github api calls.**

So right now I have a server hooked up with post-receive hook of a remote git repository. Whenever a git push is done, the server will be notified. The information will be passed to the server are standard post-receive parameters {old_revision, new_revision, ref_name}.

What the server will do is to determine what commits are pushed to the git repo, and for each of the commits pushed, generate a new email for it (including git stat info, diffs, etc.). The server **won't** a do clone of the git repo, instead it will only do api calls to a remote api server (which provides api calls similar to [**github api**](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/), let's just assuming I am using github api) in order to retrieve information about the remote git repository.

Everything isn't too many a compilation when users are just pushing standard commits to the git repo server. However, it turns out to be extremely tricky when a new branch is pushed to server.

So whenever a new branch is pushed, {ref_name} is set to be the name of the newly created a branch, {new_revision} will be the head of that branch, however {old_revision} is 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. Because there is no old_revision, I can't simply determine what range of commits are pushed to the server. Instead, I need to determine the branching point of the newly created branch.

Example:

```
-- X -- A -- B -- C -- D -- F  (master) 
          \     /   \     /
           \   /     \   /
             G -- H -- I -- J  (branch A)
```

What I need to do to find branching point - commit "A".

Since I have no access to the actual git repo,

[Finding a branch point with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git)

doesn't apply to me.

**My current solution:**

Compare **all** commits from pushed branch (sorted by time) with **all** commits from **all** branches other than pushed branch, then oldest commit that doesn't exists in other branches, then it's the branching point. However, it's obviously very inefficient, and takes way too much time.

My question is whether there is more efficient way to determine branching point (or simply the range of commits from the newly pushed branch if you have solution that don't even use branching point) only using **github api**?