# Is there a quick way to "git diff" from the point or branch origin?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have looked at various SO answers on using `git diff` and git revisions (HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, etc.) and I still haven't found an easy way to list the changes have been made since the beginning of the local branch, or since last rebase.

By *easy* I mean without having to look up and paste commit SHA or having to count how many commits I want to look back.

`git diff origin/master` is close, but it refers to remote which may have diverged since I checked out new branch from it.

I would expect something like `git diff BASE_HEAD` to be available.

...unless there's already a way to do that. Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: you want to diff against your upstream's mergebase, use @{u} and triple dot syntax.  Try `git diff @{u}...HEAD`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git, lindes answer. you might be interested in other answers too.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `git diff @{u}...HEAD`, with three dots.

With two dots, or with `HEAD` omitted, it will show diffs from changes on both sides.

With three dots, it will only show diffs from changes on your side.

Edit: for people with slightly different needs, you might be interested in `git merge-base` (note that it has plenty more options than the other answer uses).

Comment: @o11c where to specify branch name with your solution?

Comment: @jangorecki `@{u}` and `HEAD` are two separate "commitish" objects (that can be passed to `git rev-parse`). `@{u}` is short for `HEAD@{u}`, which is usually `master@{u}`.

Comment: I think using the upstream could be confusing. Why not just `git diff master...HEAD`?

Comment: @Kelvin Because those are usually the same thing.

Comment: What does the `u` in `@{u}` mean?

Comment: @TorKlingberg It's short for `@{upstream}`, this is all documented in `git rev-parse --help`

Comment: @Kelvin For me using master makes the diff output include changes made on master since the feature branch was started but that are not on the feature branch yet (i.e., the branch could be rebased).

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston I tried this but I'm not seeing the issue. The `git diff` man page also indicates you're not supposed to see changes from `master` that were made after the branch point because of the `merge-base`: _"git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B"_. Are you sure you're using 3 dots?

Comment: Yep, this was with 3 dots.  I don't think it makes a difference but my feature branch I was comparing to was remote, not local.  When using `@{u}` as the first branch the diff stat output differs compared to using `master`.

Comment: when I tried this, I got "fatal: no upstream configured for branch"

Comment: @PatrickParker in that case, you need to configure an upstream using `git branch --set-upstream-to`. There are other ways to do this at clone or branch creation time.

Comment: I'm using git 2.17.1 and this produces an empty diff, while it shouldn't.

Comment: If you use a newer git version, you can simply use `git diff --merge-base <target_branch>`

Answer (score 89):

You can find the *branch point* using `git merge-base`.  Consider `master` the mainline and `dev` the branch whose history you are interested in.  To find the point at which `dev` was branched from `master`, run:

```
git merge-base --fork-point master dev
```

We can now diff `dev` against this basis:

```
git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point master dev)..dev
```

If `dev` is the *current branch* this simplifies to:

```
git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point master)
```

For more information see the [`git-merge-base` documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base).

Comment: Note that `git merge-base` returns no output once the `dev` branch has been merged to `master`. For that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560256/how-to-get-commit-where-merged-branch-forked-from

Comment: If your base wasn't `master` this won't work. If you don't remember which branch was the base, then what?

Comment: @PatrickParker, git does not store "which branch came from which", so its not something it can infer on its own.

Answer (score 28):

You can diff the current branch from the branch start point using:

```
git diff (start point)...
```

Where (start point) is a branch name, a commit-id, or a tag.

Eg if you're working on a feature branch branched from `develop`, you can use:

```
git diff develop...
```

for all changes on the current branch since the branch point.

This was already mentioned in a comment, but I think it deserves answer status. I don't know what it will do since last rebase.

Comment: The reverse seems to be useful as well: `git diff ...develop`. It shows what has changed on 'develop' after the branch point.

Answer (score 11):

For diffs, you want the three-dot notation. If your branch is called `dev` and it branched from `master`:

```
% git diff master...dev
```

For log, you want the two-dot notation:

```
% git log master..dev
```

The revision syntax `r1..r2` (with two dots) means "everything reachable from `r2` (inclusive) but not reachable from `r1` (inclusive)". The normal way to use this is to think of `r1` and `r2` as specifying a range in a sequence of commits (`r1` exclusive, `r2` inclusive), so if you have 10 revisions, `3..7` will show you changes 4, 5, 6, and 7. It's `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` minus `{1, 2, 3}`. But `r1` doesn't necessarily have to be an ancestor of `r2`. Think of it more like a set operation where `r1` represents the entire ancestry from `r1` backwards, and `r2` represents the entire ancestry from `r2` backwards, and you're subtracting the first set from the second set.

So then:

```
git log master..dev
```

is the entire history of the branch minus the entire history of master. In other words, just the branch.

Answer (score 4):

To diff against the remote master branch:

```
git diff $(git merge-base HEAD origin/master)..
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a newer git version, you can simply use

```sh
git diff --merge-base <target_branch>
```

Which delivers (for me) identical results to currently highest voted answer of:

```sh
git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point origin/main)
```

The command was introduced in [Git Version 2.30](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.30.0.txt#L40) as:

> "git diff A...B" learned "git diff --merge-base A B", which is a
> longer short-hand to say the same thing.

So basically it another way of gettings the same result as the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810438/3813064).

Answer (score 3):

The [current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810438/6309) mentions

> Use `git diff @{u}...HEAD`, with three dots.

But... this is best done with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020).
Before, "`git diff`" used to take arguments in random and nonsense range notation, e.g. "[`git diff A..B C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) ", "[`git diff A..B C...D`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)", etc., which has been cleaned up.

See [commit b7e10b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7e10b2ca210d6a3647910fdecea33581e4eaf0d), [commit 8bfcb3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bfcb3a690126e6222f0d4f7012b0f68bb748018) (12 Jun 2020), and [commit bafa2d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bafa2d741e9dcc4d70ffcb3943e530635bb8e684) (09 Jun 2020) by [Chris Torek (`chris3torek`)](https://github.com/chris3torek).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1457886](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1457886ce2004c49661c8769f3a5246f6a340c8d), 25 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bfcb3a690126e6222f0d4f7012b0f68bb748018): improve range handling
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Chris Torek</sup>

> When [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is given a symmetric difference `A...B`, it chooses some merge base from the two specified commits (as documented).
>
> This fails, however, if there is *no* merge base: instead, you see the differences between A and B, which is certainly not what is expected.
>
> Moreover, if additional revisions are specified on the command line ("[`git diff A...B C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)"), the results get a bit weird:
>
> - If there is a symmetric difference merge base, this is used as the left side of the diff.
>   The last final ref is used as the right side.
> - If there is no merge base, the symmetric status is completely lost.
>   We will produce a combined diff instead.
>
> Similar weirdness occurs if you use, e.g., "[`git diff C A...B D`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)". Likewise, using multiple two-dot ranges, or tossing extra revision specifiers into the command line with two-dot ranges, or mixing two and three dot ranges, all produce nonsense.
>
> To avoid all this, add a routine to catch the range cases and verify that that the arguments make sense.
>
> As a side effect, produce a warning showing *which* merge base is being used when there are multiple choices; die if there is no merge base.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7e10b2ca210d6a3647910fdecea33581e4eaf0d/Documentation/git-diff.txt#L72-L79) now includes:

> ### `'git diff' [<options>] <commit> [<commit>...] <commit> [--] [<path>...]`:
>
> This form is to view the results of a merge commit.
>
> The first listed  must be the merge itself; the remaining two or more commits should be its parents.
> A convenient way to produce the desired set of revisions is to use the `{caret}@` suffix.
> For instance, if `master` names a merge commit, `git diff master master^@` gives the same combined diff as `git show master`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an alias in my `.gitconfig` to solve this task:

```
[alias]
    # See changes since branching off of main branch
    changes = "!f() { \
        current=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); \
        main=$(git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | sed 's@^refs/remotes/origin/@@'); \
        commit=$(git merge-base --fork-point \"$main\" \"$current\"); \
        git diff \"$commit\"...; \
    }; f"
```

Line-by-line, this alias:

1. Defines a shell function, `f`, which
2. computes the current branch name,
3. computes the main branch name (which could be main, master, develop, etc.),
4. computes the commit from which these two branches diverge, and
5. runs `git diff` to see the changes since this commit

Answer (score -5):

In Visual Studio 2017 there is a comfortable way to show diffs:

1. In **Team Explorer -> Branches** right click the branch and select **View History**

[image: View History]

2. In the **History - branch** control select the commits you want the diff and select **Compare Commits**

[image: Compare Commits]

You get a nice diff overview and you can open the files in compare mode.