# How to know the origin of a fork in git?

Tags: git, compare, changeset, git-fork

I'm working with a forked copy of a repository in git that was forked some years ago. I would like to see what changes have been made to the forked repo since the first time it was forked in order to understand the changes better by looking at small increments on differences between the *original* repo and the forked one instead of trying to look at a bunch of changes in lots of files that are present now in both repos.

First I need to know how to determine what changeset in the forked repo corresponds to the *original* repo, this is, that when I compare the *original* changeset, (from where the *original* repo was initially forked), with the initial forked repo changeset I get no differences, then I can go from there.

Could please anybody help me with this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a quick way to "git diff" from the point or branch origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810331/is-there-a-quick-way-to-git-diff-from-the-point-or-branch-origin)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't fetched from your origin until now, get the commit id for your current origin/master and the refetch from your origin and compare that with new origin/master (or whatever the name of the brach should be).

```
git rev-parse origin/master
git fetch origin master
git diff <commit id from rev-parse>..origin/master
```