# See which branch a branch was originally created from?

Tags: git

I have a branch that was created from an existing branch. However I don't remember which existing branch was used. How can I find out which branch this was?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git

Comment: A given branch could have _multiple_ parent branches, e.g. `master` -> `feature` -> `feature feature`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches do not have parents.

Commits have parents.

A branch name is a strictly repo-local temporary label for a currently-particular commit.

You can achieve the effect you want locally with local tracking:

```
git branch -t testing master
```

will set branch `testing` up to track branch `master`, so a `git pull` with that checked out will merge from that by default, `git rebase` will use that by default, and so forth -- and `git branch -avv` will show any configured tracking.

Any correspondence between branch names and configuration in your repo and any other repo is just convention and collaboration in action.