# Breaking a branch off into separate branches for pull requests

Tags: git, github

I have a git branch called `shared_pictures_feature`. This branch has a bunch of new files that allows users to upload photos, share photos among friends, and rate photos. To ease my fellow developer's sanity during a code review, I want to break the `shared_pictures_feature` branch into three separate branches for PR review.

Each branch should only contain the relevant files I need for a particular sub-feature. For example, the `upload_photos_feature` branch should only contain code from the `shared_pictures_feature` that deals with uploading photos. Here's my question, how do I do this with git? Is this even possible?

Comment: how would git have any notion of how your code is structured?  Did you check in each individual "piece" into their own separate commits?  Or it's all jumbled together?

Comment: Follow-up quesiton to what @Kritner just said, is your code separated by directories? It seems almost like you are saying each relevant section of code is separated by directories, but I might be reading wrong.

Comment: I easily know which files should go into each feature. All changes in my `shared_pictures_feature` are related to new files. I'm hoping there could be some way that I can decommit all of the new files from my shared_pictures_feature branch and pick what files I want to pushed for pull request.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you won't need to split an individual file into separate branches?

Comment: Absolutely not. No splitting of an individual file. Each feature is modular and does not share files among one another.

Comment: You're looking for an interactive rebase: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: be careful of time paradoxes.  Don't want to become your own grandfather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, but here is what I would suggest.

First, create and switch to your first branch.

```
git checkout -b upload_photos_feature
```

Next, find the commit where you branched `shared_pictures_feature` off of. I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git) StackOverflow question for details on how to do that. Then, in order to uncommit all of your files in that branch, you will want to do:

```
git reset --mixed <parent commit of both branches>
```

The next step will be to commit the relevant files. Just add and commit the files that you want in your `upload_photos_feature` branch, leaving the rest untouched.

Now, you will want to switch back to your original branch and restore the state you were in before.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git checkout shared_pictures_feature
```

Now, you will want to go through those steps again for each new branch. Just make sure that you do the first step of creating the new branch each time since you don't want to lose anything on `shared_pictures_feature`.

Comment: Fantastic. I will try this and report back the results. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help!