# How to list all changed or modified files from all commits in a branch

Tags: git, git-show

I need help to list all modified and changed branch files, but search all commits. The command I am using brings only the last commit.

```
git show --stat nome_branch --oneline
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+files+in+all+commits

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you need this to just have a view of what changed ? or do you want to write a script which does something with the output ?

Comment: In simple cases: `git diff --stat branch_point HEAD` will do this, you will have to find the branch_point (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git) & probably copy'n'paste the revision hash.

Or if you've merged a `main` branch onto your branch, then `git diff --stat main HEAD` (or `git diff --stat origin/main HEAD`) might be better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view for human consumption, try one of the following :

```
git log --name-only
git log --name-status
git log --stat

# maybe add --graph and --oneline options :
git log --oneline --graph --stat # or --name-only or --name-status ...
```

Comment: Resolvido. Obrigado