# Github gives me the number of commits on my branch. Can I use this as part of git rebase -i arguments?

Tags: git, github, rebase, squash

I am not, and will never be, a `git` expert, so kindly be gentle.

I have a PR branch which has—Github tells me—let's say 12 commits on it.

While I've been working on this PR, I've merged `master` (the branch it diverged from originally) into it a couple of times.  I am planning on squashing all commits down to one before this PR is accepted and merged.

I know that I am going to use `git rebase -i` to do this.  The general area of this question is how to come up with the argument to supply to this command.

Given the merges from `master` to my PR branch etc. etc., `git merge-base` doesn't give me, I don't think, the right SHA to supply as an argument to `git rebase -i`.  It will, in fact, give me the most recent commit that "came over" from `master`, instead of the earliest point at which my branch "started".

I have, of course, read [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991675/208288).  Its "shell magic" answer works, but I don't fully understand it, and I don't like relying on magic I don't understand.

My question, therefore, is: From my PR branch, **can I, instead, use this comparatively simple command:** `git rebase -i HEAD~12`, where `12` is whatever Github tells me is the number of commits on my branch?

(I am assuming in all of this, of course, that I have `push`ed my local branch to my `origin`, i.e. my local on-my-laptop branch is identical to my Github-hosted `origin` branch.  Implicit in this assumption is that if Github says 12 commits, then my on-my-laptop branch should also have exactly 12 commits.)

Is this number of commits OK to supply after the tilde (`~`)?  Is this a reliable, relatively brain-dead-easy thing to do?  Or will I trip myself up on yet another inscrutable `git` option or convention?

Comment: Typically, what you really want is `git fetch && git rebase -i origin/master`. There's no counting or anything involved here.

Comment: Will that work properly even in the presence of intermediate merges from `master` to my PR branch?

Comment: As long as they are merges *from* master *to* your PR branch, yes. Any merges going the other way are more problematic here (but might also be problematic in other ways).

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this wonderful example](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git), which answers my question exactly.  Specifically, it addresses the need for counting commits, and for designating the commit hash that should be supplied to `git rebase -i`.  It says, in part:

> A downside of the `git rebase --interactive HEAD~[N]` command is that you have to guess the exact number of commits, by counting them one by one. Luckily, there is another way:
>
> ```
> git rebase --interactive [commit-hash]
> ```
>
> Where `[commit-hash]` is the hash of *the commit just before the first one you want to rewrite from*. So in my example the command would be:
>
> ```
> git rebase --interactive 6394dc
> ```
>
> Where `6394dc` is `Feature Y`. You can read the whole thing as:
>
> ```
> Merge all my commits on top of commit [commit-hash].
> ```
>
> Way easier, isn't it?

My main issue was trying to find `[commit-hash]`.  Now I know that it is not "one of mine", but the one that *predates* mine.