# Git statistics, branch/feature analysis

Tags: git

We were using the git-flow branching model during a project.
So I want to do a quick analysis which features took the most afford to complete.

**I want some statistics about which feature branch had the most changes, the most commits before beeing merged into the main branch**.

All git analysis tools I tried so far don't have these kind of metrics.
Any ideas how to get these metrics?

Thanks so far.

Comment: Which git analysis tools did you use?

Answer (score 2):

For each branch you would like to discover the base commit (ie. when exactly the branch was created). Using solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991675/2890093):

```
branch='feature/foo'
base=$(diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent $branch) \
             <(git rev-list --first-parent master) | \
     sed -ne 's/^ //p' | head -1)
```

Now, depending on what exactly you want to see you have a couple of options:

```
# Number of non-merge commits in the branch
git log --oneline --no-merges $base..$branch | wc -l

# Summary or detailed stats (changed files, added/removed lines)
git diff --shortstat $base $branch
git diff --stat $base $branch
```