# Git log of a specific branch already merged

Tags: git, command-line, git-merge, git-branch, git-log

I'm trying to update a documentation script in Python, as my coworkers and I have recently started working with GIT.

The point I'm at and stuck with now is trying to extract a list of the names of modified files in a branch via os.system(..). Is there any way to get a list with the names of the modified files in a branch if it has already been merged into another branch? Thanks in advance!

When I try to use a "git log --name-only --pretty=format: <feature_branch>", I get the feature_branch names of the files modified, but also the ones from the parent branch, which is the master_branch from which it was created, giving me not only the files we've been working with in the branch, but the whole history, which I'm not interested in.

I've also tried doing a "git log --name-only --pretty=format: <master_branch>..<feature_branch>", but the list comes up empty, and from what I've read, this could be because the feature_branch is already merged over the master_branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get a list with the names of the modified files in a branch if it has already been merged into another branch?

Find the merge, then `git diff --name-only $merge^1...$merge^2`.  See [the three-dot `...` syntax in the `git diff` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1)

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked as expected. I'm now wondering if there's a way I can get the SHA from that merge just with the feature_branch and master_branch names, as well as the previous commit/merge SHA, since I had to get them manually from Fork tool.

Comment: You can search for the standard merge subject, "Merge branch 'feature'" using the message-search syntax, `git rev-parse "master@{/^Merge branch 'feature'}"` or if that branch is getting merged multiple times you can use `git log --pretty=%H --first-parent --grep "^Merge branch 'feature'" master`.

Answer (score 0):

Extended from the answer of the post [Finding a branch point with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git)

Use the magic bash command in the answer to find the <branch_point> commit hash

```
diff -u <(git rev-list --first-parent <feature_branch>) \
             <(git rev-list --first-parent master) | \
     sed -ne 's/^ //p' | head -1
```

Than use `git diff --name-only <branch_point>..<feature_branch>` to list changed files

Comment: That will find the *oldest* split point, though, not the most recent one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I also found out that if feature branch had merged master, this will not work as expect.